# Not show any product after submit

Tags: reactjs, django

**#React Code**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

import products from '../products'

function RecScreen() {
  const [budget, setBudget] = useState(products);
  const [items, setParts] = useState([]);

  const handleInputChange = (event) => {
    setBudget(event.target.value);
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const response = await fetch(`/api/products?price=${budget}`);
    const data = await response.json();

    setParts(data.product);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>PC Parts Recommender</h1>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          Enter your budget:
          <input type="number" value={budget} onChange={handleInputChange} />
        </label>
        <button className='btn btn-warning rounded ms-1' type="submit">Recommend Parts</button>
      </form>
      <ul>
        {items.map(product => (
          <li key={product.id}>{product.name} - ${product.price}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

export default RecScreen;
```

In this I tried to create a recommendation where user enter budget and he will get all parts of pc with in budget.
**#Django Code**

```
@require_GET
def get_parts(request):
budget = request.GET.get('budget')

    parts = [
        {'id': 2, 'category': 'power supply', 'price': 8000},
        {'id': 3, 'category': 'gpu', 'price': 400},
        {'id': 4, 'category': 'mouse', 'price': 100},
        {'id': 5, 'category': 'case', 'price': 50},
        {'id': 8, 'category': 'ram', 'price': 80},
        {'id': 9, 'category': 'processsor', 'price': 70},
    ]
    
    parts_within_budget = [part for part in parts if part['price'] <= int(budget)]
    
    sorted_parts = sorted(parts_within_budget, key=itemgetter('price'))
    return JsonResponse(sorted_parts, safe=False)
```

help me in this code after submit it not show any product in screen

In this I tried to create a recommendation where user enter budget and he will get all parts of pc with in budget.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add return keyword after '=>' arrow function's character and before parenthesis of jsx. Even this '=>' denotes return keyword. If curly brackets or rounded brackets were included, you must specify a return keyword.

This might work:

```
{items.map(product => return (
    <li key={product.id}>{product.name} - ${product.price}</li>
))}
```

Even better is to neglet the curly brackets from the start and end of `<li>` element, then there is no need of adding return statment, using only this '=>' will work.

Comment: the `return` keyword is not needed when there are no brackets after `=>`